# Mac-Os 10.14.1: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer'

Tags: terminal, xcode, macos-mojave

I have updated MacBook Pro to version 10.14.1 (Mojave).

Since that moment I have the following error when I open the terminal:

```
2018-11-12 09:03:31.057 xcodebuild[8249:72140] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
2018-11-12 09:03:31.057 xcodebuild[8249:72140] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe3fbc72310 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport'
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x00000001090bc202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

I haven't found yet a solution.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade XCode to 10.1 version.
This solves the issue.